# 100 people 100 money

Tags: arithmetic, problem-solving

Imagine you have $100$ dollars or any currency. And you also have $100$ people numbered from
Everyone one will be paid from that money.
Number one will get $1$ percent of the money, number $2$ will get $2$ percent from the  rest of the money.
For example, number $2$ will get $2$ percent from $99$ dollars, because number one got $1$ dollars from the first $100$.
The question is who will be paid the most

I really tried to solve this, but failed. Thank you in advance.

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: Welcome to SE! What is your question exactly? You said that you tried to solve it, what was your approach?

Comment: I’m sorry I forgot to add the question, the question is who will be paid the most

Comment: Hint. Try writing down some cases Let the n-th person receive P(n) and the remaining balance is then B(n). So P(1)=B(0)/100. P(2)=B(1)*2/100 etc. See where that takes you.

Comment: I don't know that there is an easy way to solve this, other than to just calculate how much money is given to the first person, the second person, the third person, and so on. It would be cool if there were, though.

Comment: Indeed this is an interesting question. Generalizing it to $n$ people, a quick simulation shows that it seems to be roughly the $\sqrt{n}$th person who comes out ahead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is clear that the first person is not paid the most since he gets $1$\$ and the second person gets $1.98$\$. Let $P(m)$ denote the amount of money paid to the $m^{th}$ person for all $m\in\mathbb{N}_{\leqslant 100}$. Let $n\in\mathbb{N}_{<100}$. Suppose that $P(n)=u$ for some $u\in \mathbb{R}^+$. Then, $P(n+1)=\frac{u(100-n)(n+1)}{100n}$. $P(n+1)\geqslant P(n) \iff\frac{(100-n)(n+1)}{100n}\geqslant 1 \iff n^2+n\leqslant 100 \iff n\leqslant 9$. Also, if $n\leqslant 9$, then $\frac{(100-n)(n+1)}{100n}> 1$. This implies that $P(1)<P(2)<\ldots<P(10)>P(11)$. If $P(k)$ is maximum for some $k>11$, then we must have had $P(k-1)\leqslant P(k)$ but this is not possible since $k-1>9$. Hence, from the above arguments, the tenth person gets paid strictly more than the rest.

EDIT: I've elaborated and structured the argument.

Comment: Please point out my error(s) if any.

Comment: I voted up +1. Looking at the ratio between the amounts of two successive people exactly as you are doing is clearly best way to go.

Comment: Perhaps some missing explanation? For example: why $u(100-n)(n+1)/(100n)$ and then change it in the next sentence? Why do you set it to $\geq 1$?

Comment: @TobiasMolenaar I'm doing that to figure out when the $(n+1)^{st}$ person gets as much or more money than the $n^{th}$ person. I'll make the argument more elaborate with an edit.

Comment: @TobiasMolenaar I hope it's clear now.

Answer (score 1):

Set $B(n)$ as the current balance of money remaining and $P(n)$ as the payout to the n-th person.

Then $B(0)=100$ and $B(n)=B(n-1)-P(n)$ as the balance decreases each turn by the value that has been paid out.

Also, $P(n)=\frac{n}{100} B(n-1)$ as the percentage that gets paid each turn.

Inserting that into the above formula we get

$$
B(n)=B(n-1)-\frac{n}{100} B(n-1)=(1-\frac{n}{100})B(n-1)
$$

We can then reduce this recursive formula to the direct value
$$
B(n)=B(0)\prod_{i=0}^n(1-\frac{i}{100})= 100 \prod_{i=0}^n(1-\frac{i}{100})
$$

Inserting that into $P(n)$ gives
$$
P(n)=\frac{n}{100}100 \prod_{i=0}^{n-1}(1-\frac{i}{100})=n \prod_{i=0}^{n-1}(1-\frac{i}{100})
$$

where we notice the arising recursive formula

$$
P(n)=\frac{n}{n-1}\left(1-\frac{n-1}{100}\right) P(n-1)
$$

If we can show that these factors are monotonically decreasing and start above $1$ for $n=0$, we can find the maximum by finding the first $n$, where the factor gets below $1$.

Thus, we compute
$$
\frac{n}{n-1}\left(1-\frac{n-1}{100}\right) >1\\
\Leftrightarrow n^2-n-100<0\\
\Leftrightarrow \frac{1}{2}-\sqrt{\frac{1}{4}+100}<n<\frac{1}{2}+\sqrt{\frac{1}{4}+100} \\
\Leftrightarrow  -9<n<10
$$

for integer numbers $n$. Thus we can conclude that $n=10$ will get the most amount of payout.

For the general case, the square root of the total number will approximately be the winning number.

Comment: @Nora Holiday I added the full solution now.